# Weird IE position absolute centering in table using rowspan

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have problem with centering an item in table on InternetExplorer when using rowspan.
[image]

i am using position absolute top 50%, transform: translateY(-50%) to center. But results are weird.This happen only on IE with rowspan. Any ideas why and how to fix it?

```css
th, td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.sortable {
  background-image:url('https://imageog.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/25/25243.png?size=1200x630f&pad=10,10,10,10&ext=png&bg=FFFFFFFF');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan=2>
      first
      <span class="sortable"></span>
    </th>
    <th rowspan=2>second</th>
    <th colspan=2>first</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>one</th>
    <th>two</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It will be nice if possible you can build a jsfiddle version.

Comment: @hanif Hey, here is fiddle - thanks for answering! https://jsfiddle.net/6jLuk8q7/3/

Comment: Please add the code to your question as a snippet, so that the question has all the relevant code ([mcve])

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working with me on **IE 10.0** , Check your IE version as **transform** CSS property started to be supported by **IE 9.0** with use of **-ms-** prefix. [W3Schools Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

[image]